# Duplicate data entry on update in Room Database

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a notes application. The user can create new notes or change the existing ones.

In this application I am trying to automatically save notes as soon as user changes the existing note. I am therefore using a `textWatcher` and I am calling the `saveNotes()` method in `onTextChanged()` method of the text wathcher. Thus, I intend here to save note everytime the user adds or removes any character from the text.

```
var ide: Int? = null  //Global Variable
```

```
//in OnCreate()
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("isViewOrUpdate", false)){
            viewOrOpenedNote = intent.getSerializableExtra("note") as Note?
            ide = viewOrOpenedNote?.id
```

In above two code sample.. the whole idea is to make variable `ide` act as a checker i.e it will return null if user is creating a new note otherwise, it will store the id of the note if the user has opened on an existing note to to view or edit the note.

**Below is the textWatcher**

```
title_edit_text.addTextChangedListener((object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                saveNote()   // here I 
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}
        }))
```

**saveNote()**

```
private fun saveNote() {
                val note = Note()
                note.setTitle(Title)

                if (ide != null) {
                    note.setId(ide!!)  // Here I am assigning the note id to `ide` in case the 
                                         `saveNote()` is called when user has opened an existing note. If 
                                          this is a new note then ide will be null automatically.
                }
                class SaveNotes : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    override fun doInBackground(vararg void: Void?): Void? {
                        NotesDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).noteDao().insertNote(note)
                        return null
                    }

                    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result)
                        ide = note.id               //This is because: If user has added a first 
                                                     character in new note, then after that an id will be 
                                                     assigned to this new database, whenever 
                                                    `saveNote()` method is called again after text change 
                                                     I need to save the changed note to the same existing 
                                                     id. I hope I am clear.

                     // ***UPDATE*** After much contemplation I have found out 
                       that here lies the problem! changing the value of ide by 
                       simply `ide = note.id` will always give null value for new 
                       note, as this id is not received from the created note, 
                       but from the blank note instance I created above. 
                    }
                }
                SaveNotes().execute()
}
```

***PROBLEM*** : The thing is even after taking above precautions, everytime I am changing a note, multiple instances of same note gets created. Example:

Suppose I type: hello

The result I get is 5 different notes with different id. And text as follows:

> h             //id = 5

> he             //id = 4

> hel           //id = 3

> hell          //id = 2

> hello         //id = 1

**NoteDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY id DESC")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertNote(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);
}
```

**Note.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "note")
public class Note implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
```

**NoteDatabase.java**

```
 public static synchronized NotesDatabase getDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if(notesDatabase == null){
           notesDatabase =  Room.databaseBuilder(context
            , NotesDatabase.class,
                    "note_db"
                    )
                   .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                   .build();
        }
        return notesDatabase;
    }


    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();
```

Comment: because you are inserting the note every time the method called inside onTextChanged.

Comment: you should use update method and update note with its id in database.

Comment: but i am using the conflict strategy right?

Comment: @ShahzadAfridi i.e @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are create a new instance (viewOrOpenedNote) every time saveNote called in onTextChange so pass the old instance note object which you get from the database or currently showing to the user.

```
//Pass the same note instance which you are showing on the screen.
@Update
fun updateNote(note: Note)

//Give note the same id as It saved in the previous note. e-g create a note instance but set Id = viewOrOpenedNote.id so that is where Conflict will arise and the database will replace it.
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertNote(note: Note) : Long
```

**Using Coroutine**

**FIRST STEP:**

```
def coroutines_android_version = '1.3.9'
// Coroutines libraries
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_core"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_android_version"
```

**SECOND STEP:**

Declear it on the class level.

```
private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
```

**THIRD STEP:**

```
ioScope.launch {
    saveNote()
}

suspend fun saveNote(){
    NotesDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).noteDao().insertNote(note)
}
```

Comment: But you must see that I am using the same Id to insert. And my conflict Strategy is replace so it should replace when two different note data with same id is saved, with the more latest one

Comment: intent  of viewOrOpenedNote  is in onCreate Method so it should work only one time

Comment: One approach you should adopt let me write it down.

Comment: After textChange method, put Hadler with delay of 3 to 5 seconds,,, to minize database calls, what actually happening is that if you type 5 words then it will generate 5 calls so if move the saveNote to onTextChanged with dealy then it will minimize the calls.

Comment: Yes this sounds good, I will try this and inform you

Comment: one more thing why using async task, it's depreacted. you can achieve this with minimum lines of code by using coroutine. If you want me to write it down then I can do it for you.

Comment: Your primary key is auto generated so your setting od id will not work and each time it will store a record with new id..You better update that record using your id

Comment: Very good point sandeep. don't know why I missed this thing.

Comment: @ShahzadAfridi Yes it would be great if you could show me how to use coroutine. Meanwhile I am trying everything that you and Sandeep mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: Thankyou very much @ShahzadAfridi I will replace async with this

Answer (score 1):

make a function inside your Dao like this

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun update(note: Note): Int
```

And put below code in your saveNote function

```
fun saveNote(item: Note) {
    database.runInTransaction {
        val id = item.id

        if(id == null)
            getNoteDao().insert(item)
        else
            getNoteDao().update(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is throwing error in your third line. What is getId() and where should I place it?

Comment: it is not recognizing that method

Comment: its probably a new method for returning the Id of a note

Comment: Thanks @rcs but what should i annotate it with? Can you please write that method?

Comment: as far as I am aware of update query, we don't need `onConflict` for update

Comment: if nothing seems to solve your problem, you can try this, place a button with an onclicklistener which triggers your `saveNote()` method and as @ Shahzad Afridi pointed to, calling a database operation for every character you type has an adverse effect on your overall app performance

Comment: Actually I intent to automatically save notes on text change and i have used that button thing before

Comment: Actually I have found out the real problem for all this. All this mess is happening because i am using this `ide = note.id` in my postExecuteMethod() The thing is that this will always be null for new note. The only way to solve this is to get the note id through runInTransaction() but i am getting error in getId()  (as I mention above)

Comment: So right now i am waiting for @Sandeepdhiman's answer.

Comment: @miraquee  I have updated my code please check

Answer (score 0):

**TO SUM IT UP**

Considering the changes you have made by pointing out the error at `ide = note.id` in your postExecuteMethod().**Do these:**

**1.**
Change your insert block in **NoteDao.java** with this

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertNote(Note note);  //long istead of void if you need the id as return
```

**2.**
Change the data-type of `ide` to **Long** from **int**

```
    var ide: Long? = null
```

**3.**
In `onCreate()`

```
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("isViewOrUpdate", false)){
            viewOrOpenedNote = intent.getSerializableExtra("note") as Note?
              ide = viewOrOpenedNote?.id?.toLong() //Convert to long
```

**4.**
You now just need to replace the `saveNote()` method with this block below.

```
private fun saveNote() {
                val database = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext) //add this here
                val note = Note()
                note.setTitle(Title)

                if (ide != null) {
                   note.setId(ide!!.toInt())  //convert to int as ide is long
                }
                class SaveNotes : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    override fun doInBackground(vararg void: Void?): Void? {
                            ide = database.noteDao().insertNote(note)  // two things inone line: first insert the note and then get the id of the note saved
                        return null
                    }

                    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result)
                        // Let this be empty
                    }
                }
                SaveNotes().execute()
}
```